# SQL : Find the minimum missing value from sequential numbers

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to find the minimum missing value from sequential numbers with only SQL?
 The example is something like this.

#### ID

1
2
3
7
9
10

How do I get the result of '4'

PS: I'm using sqlite

Comment: What is your starting number? Is it always going to be 1? or can it be any number as well?

Comment: And why do you want to find it? Do you need for some reason, e.g. column values without gaps?

Comment: not always starting by '1'..If '1' is unassigned, so it will be the output..

Comment: I want to fill the column with assigned numbers. The lack of increment feature is it skips the missing unassigned value. e.g: It generate '11' instead of '4','5','6',or'8' from the example above. So there will be lots of unassigned numbers if using the increment feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

```
select min(ID)+1
  from t1 
  where ID+1 not in (select ID from t1)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fc1ed/2)

P.S. Replace `t1` with the name of your table.